# Javascript function fails to be called when passed with an argument

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, call, argument-passing

I have a div, which onclick calls a javascript function. But it fails to do so when i call the javascript with an argument in it. This is very weird.

This below code calls the function deals() on clicking the button 'deals'

```
$("#content").append('<div class="malldetails"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><button class="left" onclick="deals()">Deals</button></a></div>');

function deals(){
alert("This works");
}
```

But the code below doesn't work.

```
$("#content").append('<div class="malldetails"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><button class="left" onclick="deals(mallName)">Deals</button></a></div>');

function deals(NameOfMall){
alert("This does not work");
}
```

I believe it should be a small problem, but just not able to figure it out. Please help me out Brilliant coders! thanks a lot!

Comment: Post your other code as well. That isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: Where is the `mallName` variable defined? Unless it's a global variable I wouldn't expect it to be accessible from an inline `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use quotes around mallName

```
$("#content").append('<div class="malldetails"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><button class="left" onclick="deals(\'mallName\')">Deals</button></a></div>');

function deals(NameOfMall){
    alert("This does not work");
}
```

Comment: mallName is a variable, I have tried the following,

    deals(' +mallName+ ')
    deals(" ' +mallName+ ' ")

Both didnt work

Comment: @LINGS In your case, `\''` is identical to `''` and `\'\'`. The only way that this solved your problem is that `mallName` was expected to be but not a string. `''+variable+''` turns a variable's value in a string.

Answer (score 0):

If `mallName` is undefined when that onclick is triggered (which I suspect it is) the alert will not occur.

Comment: oh! I am actually reading the mallName from a JSON file. After the page is loaded when I checked using the chrome developer tools, I saw the values defined for every Mall name inside the deals(mallName). Which means I believe the mallName is defined

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the javascript error on your borwser (if using IE) and see if it is showing error. If it is, then you need to declare the variable first.

So this would depend on where this javascript is placed. What shows up in the code, the error is due to the variable not defined.

Comment: The thing is, even if i hard code a mallName the javascript is still not triggered.
example : `onclick="deals("Lechmere Mall")"`
Even this fails to work. It only works when there are no arguments inside it.

Comment: LINGS - That doesn't work because you've used the wrong quotes. Try `onclick="deals(\'Lechmere Mall\')"` if you want to test with a hard-coded value. (Note that the single-quotes need to be escaped with backslashes because they're inside a string that is quoted with singles.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working.. Check whether mallName is initialized.. It may be undefined.

Comment: _"Your code is working"_ - Huh? The OP said the code is _not_ working.

Comment: Well sure, it works for you because you've defined `mallName` as a global variable with a value, i.e., you've made an assumption about code that the OP didn't show. The OP, despite having provided additional information in various comments, has still not made it clear where `mallName` is declared or how its value is set - if it's a local variable within a function then the inline event handler won't be able to access it...

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="deals("Lechmere Mall")" //wont work.
```

Check with

```
onclick="deals(\'Lechmere Mall\')" //will work.
```

Its working fine.

Check whether mallName is initialized using alert.

```
alert(mallName);
$("#content").append('<div class="malldetails"><a href="javascript:void(0);">
<button class="left" onclick="deals(mallName)">Deals</button></a></div>');

function deals(NameOfMall){
alert("This does not work");
}
```